# How to connect mix RGB with Noise Texture nodes

Tags: node-editor

I got a set up of nodes which I'd like them to connect with the noise texture so my object can has the ability to have noise and also control the colorRamp.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, are you trying to add noise to the texture (color), or the surface (normal map)?

Comment: To the texture colour

Comment: Over the whole thing, or just certain parts?

Comment: I'd like the cube to seem like it has noise on it. so I can control how grungy it will appear. and also control the color of the bricks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to cover the texture in noise, just combine it with another MixRGB node:

[image: noise]

If you want the noise to also affect the surface, just connect it to the Bump Node. I mixed it with white first so the effect is not too strong:

[image: Noise2]

Comment: its working fine, but only thing the bump doesn't work, which I have in my nodes set up.

Comment: What are you planning on connecting the bump to? Do you have a texture, or are you planning to use the noise?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy way to modify the color and bump of a material with a texture.

- You can set the *Mix RGB* node to whatever mode suits you, but I've chosen *Overlay* for this example.
- The bump is simply added to the height input of the *Bump* node.
- The *Distance* parameter of the *Bump* node is in meters, and *Strength* is a multiplier.

[image]
[image]